# Application of the Hadamard three-line theorem without an a-priori upper bound

Tags: complex-analysis, estimation

The Hadamard three-line theorem states:

> Let $f: \mathbb R + i(0,1) \to \mathbb C$ and $M_y := \sup_{x \in
> > \mathbb R} |f(x + iy)|$. If
>
> 1. f is analytic on $\mathbb R + i(0,1)$ and continuous on $\mathbb R + i[0,1]$,
> 2. $\sup_{y \in (0,1)} M_y < B$ for some $B > 0$ fixed,
>    then $M_y \leq M_0^{1-y} M_1^y$.

**Q:** Is it possible to relax the second condition to $M_y < \frac{B}{(y(1-y))^n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.

**My thoughts:**
The supremum is still bounded on every subset, $\sup_{y \in (\epsilon,1-\epsilon)} M_y < \infty$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ fixed.
Is it possible to estimate $M_y$ close to the boundary by $M_0$ and $M_1$?

This is related to the question whether $y \mapsto M_y$ is continuous. This is certainly not true for any analytic function, e.g. $f(z) = e^{iz}$ satisfies $M_0 = 1$ by $M_y = \infty$ for any $y>0$ fixed.
However, we additionally have the property that $M_y < \infty$ for any $y>0$. Then, it seems obvious that $\lim_{y \searrow 0} M_y = M_0$ (at least no counter-example comes to my mind). But I am unsure how this can be proven.

Comment: $M$ is logarithmically convex hence is continuous by basic stuff about convex functions wherever is finite; and for your question consider the function $f(z)\times z(1-z)^n$ which satisfies the usual hypothesis and apply Hadamard o it

Comment: @Conrad
1. $M_y$ is only convex is the hypothesis of the theorem is satisfied, right? So in my case it does not hold generally.

2. $f(z)$ diverges as the imaginary part goes to zero, it does not just have a pole in $z=0$. So multiplying with $z^n$ will not help as for example $f(z) = 1/(z-1)^n$ would still diverge.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want - $f$ is supposed to be continuous on the imaginary axis as otherwise it doesn't really make sense to talk about supremum at finite points at least etc - I mean you can take $f$ locally bounded on the imaginary line, but then probably you need some additional hypothesis; it's very unclear what your hypothesis are (as you said you want to modify only 2 while 1 clearly states $f$ continuous etc), what your conclusion wants to be etc - Hadamard three line theorem and associated ideas like Phragmen Lindelof are generally concerned with the behavior at infinity

Comment: What is unclear about the hypothesis? Yes, $f$ is continuous, so it is bounded on the imaginary axis $\sup_{y\in [0,1]} |f(x + iy)| \leq C_x < \infty$ for $x$ fixed. At the same time, it is bounded at real infinity $\sup_x |f(x + iy)| < \infty$ for $y$ fixed. 

My question is whether these two assumptions are sufficient to conclude uniform boundedness on the strip $\sup_x \sup_y |f(x + iy)| < \infty. I.e. are they sufficient to show that $f$ indeed does not diverge when approaching the boundary, and if so how can this be proven.

Comment: The hypothesis are unclear as written above - if you assume that $f$ is bounded on each vertical line of a strip with a bound depending on the abscissa, you need to assume that $f$ is of finite order - or not bigger than $e^{e^{(\delta-\epsilon)|y|}}$ where $\delta$ depends the horizontal length of the strip to conclude boundness in the strip - and then it's enough to assume boundness on the end lines of the strip actually; otherwise there are entire functions that are bounded on any line and are not constant and can be made unbounded on a strip of your choice

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "unclear". Is it: 1. that you do not understand my assumptions? 2. that you think they are not sufficient (i.e. I *need* to assume something stronger)? 3. that my assumptions are equivalent to something more clear and I should replace them?  4. Contradictory (but I do not think so)?